# XPathDocument Can't Load

Tags: c#, xml

I create a `XPathDocumnet` and give it a `xml file`, but it doesn't load the document. I mean it takes infinity to load because there's no exception or something like that. Here's the code:

```
string root = @"http://emtehan.roshd.ir";
WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
webclient.DownloadFile(root, "doc.xml");
XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument("doc.xml");
```

Comment: check to make sure the doc.xml is formatted properly.

Comment: that is, most likely, the issue. to parse xhtml like in your case use the htmlagilitypack - http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: Unfortunately many, many many web pages are not xml compliant. That idea hasn't really caught on. :(

Comment: Calling http://emtehan.roshd.ir/doc.xml only gives "The page you requested was not found.". So how would that ever work...

Comment: do you know that `http://emtehan.roshd.ir/doc.xml` returns 404?

Comment: @shriek that explains the perpetual wait with no exception ...

Comment: Why not var loaded = XDocument.Load(@"http://emtehan.roshd.ir");

Comment: It downloads emtehan.roshd.ir it doesn't download ~/doc.xml

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your target site - it doesn't use standard tags, I mean there is a problem in parsing xml. It seems you just want to extract urls from code. So use a sample httpclient to download row html contents then use ereg functions to extract urls.
Plus, if you just want to leech a site there are many good apps like websote offline explorer(trial) or even some open source projects(refrence:google.com!)

*ereg method is much quicker than parsing all code! Check some open source projects code, all of them work like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference System.Xml.Linq.dll

and code is here

```
///Reference the namespace
using System.Xml.Linq;
try
{ 
    ///Read xml from url
    var doc = XDocument.Load("MyUrl");
    ///Write it to local file
    doc.Save("MyFile.xml");
}
catch(Exception exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
}
```

Will it solve the problem?

**Edited**

```
var response = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://emtehan.roshd.ir/").GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
var output = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

It gives the html to string then you can do any operation you want

Comment: Exception:"Reference to undeclared entity 'nbsp'. Line 42, position 37" .it can not understand it

Comment: are you using .Net version lower than 3.5?

Comment: No It's .Net 4.  I can run the program, but it can't understand the html document from the site

Comment: what should i do next with the returned string?

Comment: Ok lets start again do you want to get xml data or html.. Given url gives html data.

Comment: html. but isn't html a kind of xml?

Comment: yes but xml can be deserialized html is hard and unnesessary. XML can be used to save data in the form of List, List of List.... Html is used for presenting purpose.

Comment: As your goal is to save data to file you can use File.AppendAllText("FileName", YourString);

Comment: but it is not the problem i wanna find some special links in the html file using XPathNavigator